# Magento - Export all products & categories tables

Tags: php, database, magento, export

My entire Magento installation has failed me over time so I want to create a clean new install directory and import everything in there.

Problem - can't use the export tool because it's one of many pages which displays a 404 error in the admin. Had this problem for a week now and tried pretty much every solution I've found on the internet with no success.

My solution - export all tables necessary for all 600+ products in the shop. I'll need products & everything linked to them as well as categories. There is also another extension I installed called Advanced Product Options and I'll need data from this as well. I'll also download the media/catalog folder and upload this to the new installation.

Could someone give me like a list of tables I'd need for this to work?

Would really appreciate some help here.

Thanks in advance.

Edit - My hosting has no SSH or shell so I can't use command prompts to export the products.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the 404 error try run the follow MySQL command:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE
customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Or use this tool:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool

Answer (score 0):

Try first writing this in the SQL command line in you phpmyadmin
ALTER TABLE catalog_category_entity ENGINE=INNODB;  ALTER TABLE core_store ENGINE=INNODB;

If that doesn't work try the Data Base Repair Tool from magento